# Every infinite group has a non-trivial subgroup

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, infinite-groups

> **Theorem**:
>
> **Every infinite group $G$ has a subgroup $H$ that is non-trivial ($H \ne G, \lbrace e \rbrace$).**

**Proof:** This will be a proof by contradiction. So we will assume every subgroup is trivial and bring the cyclic subgroups to the table.

For the non-identity $\forall x \in G$, $\langle x \rangle \ne \lbrace e \rbrace$. Hence $\langle x \rangle = G.$ Thus every non-identity element of $G$ must be a generator of $G$. Then it must be possible to write any element as the exponent of another. For $\forall y \in G$,

$$y =x^n.$$

Since $x^2 \in G$ by closure, it is also a generator and we must be able to write $x$ as an exponent of $x^2$. Yet this is not possible unless our group is finite. So our assumption must be false and our conjecture must be true. $\square$

Is my proof watertight? And is it rigorous enough? Thanks for your reviews.

Comment: You do not need to phrase it as a proof by contradiction. Take $x\in G$, $x\neq e$. If $x^2=e$, then $\langle x\rangle\neq G$, since $\langle x\rangle$ is finite. If $x^2\neq e$, and $x\in\langle x^2\rangle$, then $x=x^{2k}$ for some $k$, so $x^{2k-1}=e$, hence $\langle x\rangle$ is finite, nontrivial, and distinct from $G$. And if $x\notin \langle x^2\rangle$, $x^2\neq e$, then $\langle x^2\rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ and you are done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is right, but you should avoid claims like

> Yet this is not possible unless our group is finite.

since this doesn't give your reason for the "unless."

In your case, you perhaps could explicitly note that $G = \langle x \rangle$ implies $x$ cannot have finite order.  Then show that $x \in \langle x^2\rangle$ implies $x$ has finite order.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tiny hole: $x^2$ is not a generator of $G$ if it is equal to the identity element $e$. So you also need to consider the separate case that $x^2=e$. Otherwise, it looks good.

Comment: $x^2$ can't be equal to the identity element because by assumption $x$ is a generator of an infinite group, so that exponents of $x$ are all distinct (otherwise there is no way resulting cyclic group can be infinite too). Since $x^0 = e$, it follows that $x^2 \ne e$.